# profile of circular image - more efficient way to do it?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I need to get a 1-D profile of a circular image, for example 256x256 sin(R) image
[image: 256x256 sin(R) image]

I've written a matlab function for the task but it turns out to be very un-efficient.
the function averages over radius intervals of the original images.

**matlab profiler reveals that the first line in the for-loop [indxs=find(...)] 
takes ~86% of the running time.**

i need to run the function on a some thousands of simulated images (some larger then 256x256) and it takes very long time to complete.

does anyone knows how can i make this code run faster?
maybe someone has another, more efficient way to do the task??

i also tried to convert to function into C++ & mex file  using matlab coder
but it took longer (x3) to perform the task, might be because the sub-function- "findC"
uses some 2D-ffts to find the center of the image.

Thanks you All,
Dudas

My Matlab function:

```
function [sig R_axis Center]= Im2Polar (imR,ch,Center_Nblock)
% Converts Circular image to 1-D sig
% based on true image values w/o interpolation

% Input -
% imR - circular sinuns image
% ch - number of data-points in output signal (sig)
% Center_Nblock - a varible related to the image center finding method

% Output -
% sig - 1D vector of the circular image profile
% R_axis - axis data-points for sig
% Center - image center in pixels


[Mr Nr] = size(imR); % size of rectangular image
[Center]=findC(imR,Center_Nblock);
Xc=Center(1);
Yc=Center(2);

rMax=sqrt((Mr/2)^2 + (Nr/2)^2);

x=[0:1:Mr-1]-Xc+1;
y=[0:1:Nr-1]-Yc+1;

[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
[TH,R] = cart2pol(X,Y);

% Assembling 1-D signal
sig=single([]);
ii=1;
dr=floor(rMax)/ch;
V=dr:dr:floor(rMax);

for v=V
    indxs=find((v-dr)<=R & R<v);**
    sig(ii)=mean(imR(indxs));
    Nvals(ii)=length(indxs);

    ii=ii+1;
end %for v

R_axis=V-dr/2;

end % of function
```

Comment: Well, for one thing you could just remove that `find` and use the logical index directly (replacing the third line in the loop by `Nvals(ii) = sum(idxs)`). MATLAB often underlines `find` in the editor window and tells you it's slow.

Comment: It would be good that you show an example of the input variables and the function 'findC'.

Comment: @wakjah- Nvals is not a really part of the algorithm it is just a control variable that tells me how many points have been averaged for every value in the output signal.   anyway Ive tried also -`sig1(ii)=mean(imR(  (v-dr)<=R & R<v)  )` to avoid `find` it takes the same run time period. @tashuhka the function `findC` use the image and another argument that determine a size for 2D-fft blocks that is used in the rings centering method

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want to integrate the image values within a series of annular rings? If I were doing this I'd probably pre-compute a template of the indices for each ring in advance, relative to the center of any image, pass it to the function and shift the values relative to whereever the actual center of the image occurs. I don't see why indxs has to be found at run-time, e.g 10 pixels to the left and 5 pixels up from the center pixel (say (128,128)) will always be counted in the same annulus.

Comment: @bogle - 10x for your reply, i understand what you mean, the thing is that the number of annulars that need to be average can change from one operation to another. 
even if i make it constant(and im willing to do it in order to shorten simulation run-time), i don't have an idea how to implement your suggestion efficiently with the locally-randomize ring's center position. can you please give a short example to your suggestion. 10x again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from the comments here's an example of something I might try.  Let's work with a 9x9 example.  Suppose you have the following annulus.

```
A =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Then the indices of your sort of mask are, lets say [k n]

```
 >> [k n]

 ans =

 3     2
 4     2
 5     2
 6     2
 7     2
 2     3
 3     3
 4     3
 6     3
 7     3
 8     3
 2     4
 3     4
 7     4
 8     4
 2     5
 8     5
 2     6
 3     6
 7     6
 8     6
 2     7
 3     7
 4     7
 6     7
 7     7
 8     7
 3     8
 4     8
 5     8
 6     8
 7     8
```

Now have a 9x9 matrix of zeroes on hand called B, we can shift the whole thing over to the left by one pixel as follows using the formula (i+9*(j-1)) to convert double index to a single index.

```
 >> B=zeros(9,9);
 >> B((k)+9*(n-2))=1

 B =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Or move down and to the right as follows

```
 >> B=zeros(9,9);
 >> B((k+1)+9*(n-0))=1

 B =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
 0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
```

As long as it doesn't go out of bounds you should be able to shift a single annular mask around with a simple addition to put the center at the image center.

Comment: Hi @bogle, 10x for the example. generally the rings center can be shifted within sub-pixel units. so it is a partial solution to the task. (i need to calculate accurately the phase of the sinus) ill check what the meaning of rounding rings center s to the nearest pixel on the results.